# Determine if a relation is transitive.

Tags: relations

Decide if the following relation on X is transitive: X = Z, with relation a R b if −7 ≤ a − b ≤ 7

By adding

−7 ≤ a − b ≤ 7 and −7 ≤ b − c ≤ 7

by parts, I found

−14 ≤ a − c ≤ 14

, which gives a clue but is not enough since I need to prove (or disprove) that

−7 ≤ a − c ≤ 7... any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you've noticed that the obvious method of proof doesn't work. Have you tried to disprove it? How might you do that?

Comment: @user3482749 well one obvious way is to try to reach a contradiction starting from −7 ≤ a − c ≤ 7... let me try that and I will come back with the results. Also, to be honest, my gut told me that this was true, that's why I did not try disproving it.

Comment: To disprove a thing, you only need to find one counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show a relation $R$ is transitive, we must show $aRb$ and $bRc$ implies $aRc$.

Your relation $R$ is equivalent to $aRb$ if $|a - b| \leq 7$, which is **not** transitive.

Suppose $x = 10, y = 3, z = 0$. Then, we have $xRy$ because $|x - y| = 7 \leq 7$. Also, we have $yRz$ because $|y - z| = 3 \leq 7$. However, we do not have $xRz$ because $|x - z| = 10 > 7.$

Thus, we have a contadiction.

Comment: That's right... I am relatively new to this stuff, so trying to find a counterexample, although a simple tool, did not pop in my mind. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.